# Google Tag Manager - How to avoid data loss

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Manager to register events with Google Analytic. At one plance I am changing url on the changeof a dropdown. I want to track the same event on Google Analytics. I am worried what would happen if page is changed before event is registered with GA. Could you please let me know if there is a feature in GTM that can ensure that page is not changed before event is registered with GA.

Here is the code that will execute on the change of the dropdown

```
var targetCityChangedEventName = "TargetCityChanged";

$("#location", topHeader).bind({
        "change": function(ev, obj) {
            dataLayer.push({event : targetCityChangedEventName });
            var url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/" + $(this).val();
            window.location = url;
     }
});
```

Comment: If you use built-in event listeners in GTM, they all have hit callback functionality.

Comment: @PetrHavlík, but there is no onchange handler, is there ?

Comment: Eike, I think you are correct :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ga.js (asynchronous Analytics) you can set an hit callback (a macro that returns a function) in the tag template under "advanced configuration and do the redirect there (possibly you'd need a separate analytics tag just the change event).

If you use Universal Analytics there was a discussion at the Tag Manager Google Group a while ago where [Googles Brian Kuhn suggested](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/tag-manager/123YJMM-JNk/oPZOXdRDNWYJ) the following way ( I have not tested this):

> In the meantime, have you tried this?

```
dataLayer.push({callback:
 function() {
     alert(123);   
});
```

> Then, create a dataLayer macro that reads the "callback" key.  Then,
>   use that macro as the value of a "fields to set" pair on your UA tag,
>   under the field name "hitCallback".

Instead of the alert you'd do the redirect.

In case that's not clear, a hit callback is a function that can be passed to the tracking calls and is executed after the tracking call has executed.

Comment: Macro type "Data Layer Variable", "Data Layer Variable Name" set to "callback". As I've said I haven't tested this myself (I assumed it would work since it was suggested by a Google employee), so if you use this sucessfully could you leave a comment ?

Comment: I will - Thanks for responding so quick. Wasn't sure what he meant by the "key

Comment: Works perfectly! I added a note to the answer. Hopefully that will clarify the shit out of it :-)

Comment: How do I create a dataLayer macro that reads the callback key? Is that expressed in code, or something that needs to be setup within analytics itself?

Comment: See the second comment to this post - you can pass the callback in exactly the same way you would pass a variable to the dataLayer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the same issue by simply **inserting a delay**. The `dataLayer.push` doesn't need to return anything, so a 100 millisecond delay is sufficient in 99% of the cases for the `dataLayer.push` to be executed.

```
dataLayer.push({ ... });
setTimeout( function(){ window.location = ...; }, 100 );
```

Note that the GTM preview/debug mode gives false positives - you must make sure that your tags are actually being fired, in my case my event was for a virtual pageview and I could see the results in RealTime Analytics.  Without the delay, I could see that the tag was not being fired.